# Removing the Timestamp from a NumPy Array

Tags: python, numpy, timestamp

I'm performing a linear regression on a dataset (Excel file) which consists of a Date column, a scores column and additional column called Predictions with NaN values which will be used to store the predicted values.

I have found that my independent variable, X, contains timestamps which I was actually expecting...? Perhaps I'm doing something wrong, or actually missing something out..?

Top of the original dataset:

```
       Date    Score
0 2019-05-01 4.607744 
1 2019-05-02 4.709202 
2 2019-05-03 4.132390 
3 2019-05-05 4.747308 
4 2019-05-07 4.745926
```

Create the independent data set (X)
Convert the dataframe to a numpy array

```
X = np.array(df.drop(['Prediction'],1))
```

Remove the last '30' rows

```
X = X[:-forecast_out]
print(X)
```

Example of output:

```
[[Timestamp('2019-05-01 00:00:00') 4.607744342064972]
[Timestamp('2019-05-02 00:00:00') 4.709201914086133]
[Timestamp('2019-05-03 00:00:00') 4.132389742485806]
[Timestamp('2019-05-05 00:00:00') 4.74730802483691]
[Timestamp('2019-05-07 00:00:00') 4.7459264970444615]
[Timestamp('2019-05-08 00:00:00') 4.595303054619376]
```

Create the dependent data set (y)
Convert the dataframe to a numpy array

```
y = np.array(df['Prediction'])
```

Get all of the y values except the last '30' rows

```
y = y[:-forecast_out]
print(y)
```

Some of the output:

```
[4.63738251 4.34354486 5.12284464 4.2751933  4.53362196 4.32665058
 4.77433793 4.37496465 4.31239161 4.90445026 4.81738271 3.99114536
 5.21672369 4.4932632  4.46858993 3.93271862 4.55618508 4.11493084
 4.02430584 4.11672606 4.19725244 4.3088558  4.98277563 4.97960989
```

Split the data into 80% training and 20% testing

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
```

Create and train the Linear Regression  Model

```
lr = LinearRegression()
```

Train the model

```
lr.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

The error:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp'
```

Clearly the dataset X doesn't like having the timestamp, and like I say, I wasn't really expecting it.

Any help on removing it (or perhaps I need it!?) would be great. As you can, see I'm simply looking to perform a simple regression analysis

Comment: Are the timestamps in the same column in the Excel file as well?

Comment: @MRL drop 'Date' AND 'Prediction' during the initialization of X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not include the Timestamps (Date) in your creation of 'X'.

The data set is already ordered, so do you really need the time stamps?  Another option, try reassigning the index.  In either case, I think, do not try to pass Timestamps as argument-data.

**Implement changes at this step:**

```
X = np.array(df.drop(['Prediction'],1))
```

**Do something like:**

```
 X = np.array(df.drop(['Date', 'Prediction'],1))
```

Comment: Cheers. Not sure why the timestamps were being passed as data, I've never had that issue before.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be solved by using the date timestamp as an index field instead. You can try reset_index to re-assign index.